# How to Use Custom Chrome Tabs in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

How to implementation of Custom Chrome Tabs in Jetpack compose?

Is there any lib for Chrome tab?
Please share reference link or sample code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Custom chrome tabs have nothing to do with compose since there is no UI render on your part. Use them like you would in View system, just make sure you are using context from `LocalContext.current`

Answer (score 3):

> implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.4.0'

```kotlin
val context = LocalContext.current
var mCustomTabsServiceConnection: CustomTabsServiceConnection? = null
var mClient: CustomTabsClient? = null
var mCustomTabsSession: CustomTabsSession? = null

mCustomTabsServiceConnection = object : CustomTabsServiceConnection() {
     override fun onCustomTabsServiceConnected(componentName: ComponentName, customTabsClient: CustomTabsClient) {
         // Pre-warming
         mClient = customTabsClient
         mClient?.warmup(0L)
         mCustomTabsSession = mClient?.newSession(null)
    }

    override fun onServiceDisconnected(name: ComponentName) {
        mClient = null
    }
}

CustomTabsClient.bindCustomTabsService(context, "com.android.chrome", mCustomTabsServiceConnection)
val customTabsIntent = CustomTabsIntent.Builder(mCustomTabsSession)
    // .setToolbarColor(color)
    .setShowTitle(true)
    .build()
    
customTabsIntent.launchUrl(context, Uri.parse("https://google.com"))
```

Comment: This would have to be wrapped in some side effect, since it might be called during every recomposition

Answer (score 0):

```kotlin
fun Context.launchCustomTabs(url: String, useIncognito: Boolean?) {
    CustomTabsIntent.Builder().build().apply {
        if (useIncognito == true) { 
            intent.putExtra(
                "com.google.android.apps.chrome.EXTRA_OPEN_NEW_INCOGNITO_TAB", 
                true
            )
        }
    }
    .launchUrl(this, Uri.parse(url))
}
```

From your compose code:

```kotlin
val context = LocalContext.current
....
....
onClick = {
   context.launchCustomTabs(url = "https://google.com", useIncognito = false)
}
....
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```kotlin
rememberLauncherForActivityResult(contract = StartActivityForResult())
```

Create your custom tab intent with this, and launch the custom tab as you would like with any other instantiated launcher:

```kotlin
CustomTabsIntent.Builder().build().intent.apply { 
    setData(url) 
}
```